# Save a ListView into Settings.settings?

Tags: c#, listview, settings.settings

How can I save a ListView with multicolumns into Settings.settings and load them upon running?
I'm trying to save a ListView with 3 columns. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Bind the listview to some data structure.
2. Serialize is using xmlseriualizer - then you can save the result into the Settings.

Restoring is done using deserialize.

```
StringWriter output = new StringWriter(new StringBuilder());
XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(this.GetType());
s.Serialize(output,this);
var result = output.ToString()
```

Comment: Got an example of how I can use XmlSerializer/Deserialize?

Comment: Am I required to make an XML file?

Comment: No - you can save the xml to a string instead - see above